# How to use parameters in Command line .cmd

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, command-line-arguments

It's the first time that I write a .cmd file

I need to decrypt a file using some command.. lets use a simple example.
all that I need is how can I let the user enter parameters after he double clicks the .cmd file and how can I use arguments in the cmd.

let's say I need the user to enter his name after he double clicks the .cmd file:

> hello
>   please enter your name: // here the user should enter his name lets say Peter
>   how are u Peter         // here the file is using arg0 and waits the user to enter his name before that the program will continue
>   please enter the path that you want ...  :   // here the user enters the path were he wants to save the output files  ...
>   the file has been succefully decrypted in //path

so the code that I need has to be similar to :

```
echo hello
wait()//till the user enters his name
echo hello arg0
echo please enter the path that you want ... 
echo the file has been succefully decrypted in arg1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in a .cmd file:

```
@echo off &setlocal &cls
echo.hello
set /p "name=please enter your name: "
echo.how are u %name%
set /p "fpath=please enter the path that you want ... : "
echo.the file has been succefully decrypted in %fpath%
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
set /p name=enter your name:
echo how are you %name% ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to receive input from keyboard and use it as variables in batch file.

why don't you try a c++ console application?

Comment: It is possible you can try the 2 answers above it will work !!